# php imap echoing weird headers..how can I fix this?

Tags: php, regex, header, imap, gmail-imap

Here is my PHP Code for grabbing gmail emails and echoing them to a webpage:

```
<?php


                            /* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'username@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

 /* begin output var */
 $output = '';

 /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);

  /* for every email... */
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {

  /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1);



    $DateFormatted = str_replace("-0500", "", $overview[0] -> date);



    /* output the email header information */
    $output .=  $overview[0] -> subject ;
    $output .=  $DateFormatted ;




    //$bodyFormatted = preg_replace("/This e-mail(.*)/","",$message);
 //$bodyFormatted = preg_replace("/Ce courriel(.*)/","",$bodyFormatted);
    /* output the email body */
    $output .=  $message;


                          }

echo $output;
                        }

                        /* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

                                ?>
```

The problem I am having is that I keep getting weird headers blurted out along with the message body and I dont know why. I cant use str replace or Regex because the numerical part of the headers is generated different each time so I really need a reliable way of doing this. I am out of ideas and I need help.
 Also getting some random "=" signs

Output:

```
SiteA Connectivity Issues (resolved)Tue, 6 Dec 2011 13:59:59 **------_=_NextPart_001_01CCB449.406E7C50 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable =20** Please be advised www.siteA.com is no longer experiencing issues. The site is up and fully operational once again. =20 IMPACT: www.siteA.com was experiencing connectivity issues.=20 =20 UPDATE: Connectivity issues have been resolved. Root cause analysis and reporting will be performed tomorrow during business hours. **=20 ------_=_NextPart_001_01CCB449.406E7C50 Content-Type: text/html; charset="US-ASCII" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable**



Please be advised www.siteA.com is no longer = experiencing issues. The site is up and fully operational once = again.



IMPACT:

www.siteA.com was experiencing connectivity issues.



UPDATE:

Connectivity issues have been = resolved. Root cause analysis and reporting will be performed tomorrow during = business hours.


**------_=_NextPart_001_01CCB449.406E7C50--**
```

Comment: Are you talking about the MIME-boundaries? The `------_=_NextPart_001_01CCB449.406E7C50-` part...

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing are not headers, as such, they are MIME boundaries for a multipart message. Your message contains the same data in two formats - HTML and plain text. This is very common for email bodies, you will need access to the `Content-Type:` header of the email to parse it correctly. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages).

[This](http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/3169/thread/11/) may help you parse it and deal with it correctly, as may [this](http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/).